# Bash - Concatenating backslash while joining an array

Tags: arrays, bash, gruntjs

I've been trying to figure out a bash script to determine the server directory path, such as D:\xampp\htdocs, and the project folders name, such as "my_project", while Grunt is running my postinstall script.  So far I can grab the projects folder name, and I can get an array of the remaining indices that comprise the server root path on my system, but I can't seem to join the array with an escaped backslash.  This is probably not the best solution (definitely not the most elegant) so if you have any tips or suggestions along the way I'm amendable.

```
# Determine project folder name and server root directory path
bashFilePath=$0                           # get path to post_install.sh
IFS='\' bashFilePathArray=($bashFilePath) # split path on \
len=${#bashFilePathArray[@]}              # get array length

# Name of project folder in server root directory
projName=${bashFilePathArray[len-3]}      # returns my_project

ndx=0
serverPath=""
while [ $ndx -le `expr $len - 4` ]
do
    serverPath+="${bashFilePathArray[$ndx]}\\" # tried in and out of double quotes, also in separate concat below
    (( ndx++ ))
done

echo $serverPath # returns D: xampp htdocs, works if you sub out \\ for anything else, such as / will produce D:/xampp/htdocs, just not \\
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only prefix command invocations, not variable assignments, with `IFS`, so your line

```
 IFS='\' bashFilePathArray=($bashFilePath)
```

is just a pair of assignments; the expansion of `$bashFilePath` is unaffected by the assignment to `IFS`. Instead, use the `read` builtin.

```
IFS='\' read -ra bashFilePathArray <<< "$bashFilePath"
```

Later, you can use a subshell to easily join the first few elements of the array into a single string.

```
serverPath=$(IFS='\'; echo "${bashFilePathArray[*]:0:len-3}")
```

The semi-colon is required, since the argument to `echo` is expanded before `echo` actually runs, meaning `IFS` needs to be modified "globally" rather than just for the `echo` command. Also, `[*]` is required in place of the more commonly recommended `[@]` because here we are making explicit use of the property that the elements of such an array expansion will produce a single word rather than a sequence of words.

Comment: You need to use `-r` or else backslashes would just be interpreted as quotes: `IFS='\' read -ra bashFilePathArray <<< "$bashFilePath"`.

Comment: Oh, right, this is a use case where backslashes are guaranteed to appear in the input.

Comment: +1 Might also be useful to point out that using `[*]` opposed to `[@]` is required when needing to expand the array to a single word.

Comment: Thanks, that works great.  Just so I understand what is happening you're reading from stdin, which is being redirected using <<< and supplied with a string, and then split on the reset of the IFS delimiter. Then you grab all the array elements as a single word using [*] from 0 to length - 3, but then you use IFS again to replace the spaces in the array.  So IFS is automatically unset during execution and it has to be set again to the appropriate delimiter?